# Anaconda Spyder got error output in Python Console

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I installed Anaconda (2.7.12) on Windows 10, `PATH = C:\Anaconda`, when I open Spyder then switch to Python Console and type some code below I get:
[image: Problem]

Next, I open python.exe in Anaconda2, there is no such problem, so maybe the problem comes from Spyder. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What issues are there? I don't see any error messages? Please don't post screen shots, please post the text of the error message.

Comment: The issue is in the Python console. It breaks the output.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug that has not been solved yet as seen on the spyder github page. Please keep a look at this page for any updates: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/

Comment: Got it! I have a Win10 computer in my lab, also installed Anaconda initially, and Python console works correctly.

Comment: The computer that have output problem it has been installed pythonxy, then I uninstall it and install Anaconda. Since one day Win10 updated and Spyder in pythonxy cannot open anymore.

Comment: Try downgrading the Windows to 8 or 7. As I said, Spyder has many bugs and they are trying to fix all of them as soon as possible.

Comment: So sad! I use it due to it can show all variable value and plot.

Comment: If I were you, raise this issue on their Github to gain more attention and a possible solution.

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) @radiosan, this bug is known to us, but unfortunately we don't know how to fix it. Please use the IPython console instead, which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Got it! Sorry for forgetting post solution. Well actually I have solved it by creating new environment to install 'Spyde' and pyqt4.10(because my app built from) in Anaconda. Then Python Console in 'Spyder' works normally.

Comment: There we go. Some progress!